# Does TortoiseSVN commit has an option of opening exe?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

I've set up BugId property to my files in the repository. This means that on the commit window, I have a field which the developers type the issue number of the bug and it's shown in the log message of the commit.

I wanted to know if there a possibility that once I click on the commit button, before the commit itself, an exe file will be executed.

I'm not referring to the pre-commit hook, as it runs after I click on the commit button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want this file to run on your client check the TortoiseSVN help 4.30.8. [Client Side Hook Scripts](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks).

There is a Start-commit hook for TortoiseSVN that runs just before the commit dialog is shown.

I have just tried this and it works just fine.

[alt text http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/760/hook.png](http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/760/hook.png)

File test.bat contains only `exit 0` command and I can clearly see the console window opening and closing before the commit dialog is shown.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to execute my exe/bat file BEFORE the user presses the commit button. I'm familiar with all the SVN hooks.

Comment: I tried the start-commit hook. It executes after the commit button is pressed.

Comment: Thank you, I tried one more time and I got it. it works fine.

Comment: Does this go to version control? Because it would be cool if I could make this into version control (I'm making a script to put subversion revision in the assembly info of a C# project).

Comment: How can I pass the commit number / commit id? I want to automate the synching of data from my production server using putty

Comment: @ClannadSystem I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but I suggest you start a new question with a little bit more info.

Answer (score 0):

In TortoiseSVN 1.5 and up, you can define **Client-Side Hook Scripts**. Read about them in the excellent TortoiseSVN help system. In particular, for your purposes, look at the *Start-Commit* and *Pre-Commit* hooks.

Comment: although the Start-Commit supposed to be executed before the commit dialog opens, it doesn't. The hook is executed after I press the commit button.

Comment: @Oded: I'm not sure what you mean by the "commit button". TortoiseSVN, as I know it, has a "Commit" menu item, which if triggered brings up the Commit dialog box, which has an "Ok" button. The Start-Commit hook runs before the dialog opens - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59007/how-do-i-use-a-start-commit-hook-in-tortoisesvn-to-setup-a-custom-log-entry/59379 for an exmple usage.

Comment: I ment the "OK" button. I've created a batch file that only creates a simple text file and put in in the start-commit hook. it still doesn't launch the batch file until I press the OK button.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure, other than looking carefully into the accepted answer on the other question about the API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59007/how-do-i-use-a-start-commit-hook-in-tortoisesvn-to-setup-a-custom-log-entry/59349#59349

Answer (score 0):

You should consider implementing an [IBugtraqProvider](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-ibugtraqprovider.html). That interface was specifically designed for this purpose.

You might want to use the `CheckCommit()` method.